# Setting /proc/irq/100/smp_affinity is not keeping

Tags: linux, irq

I am setting the smp_affinity mask on my two NIC IRQs (100 and 101) to a specific cpu core - `echo 0002 > smp_affinity` - but the new value only stays for a couple seconds then starts randomly cycling through all the cpu cores again. Is there another setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be because my system was running `irqbalance` which overrides the settings I was making. Turning off `irqbalance` resulted in my settings staying in effect.